# How to get window id of the popup window that is created by chrome.windows.create()

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

How to get window-id of the popup window that is created by chrome.windows.create()

**background.html**

```
window_options={
"url":"another_popup.html"
"type":"popup"
};

chrome.windows.create(window_options,call_back_function)
call_back_function(Window window)
{
console.log(window.id) 
//prints the window's id properly
}
```

**another_popup.html(the page that the popup window holds)**

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
console.log(window.id)
//says ,cannot find property and gives a null 
 });
```

Comment: And your question is?.. Your example contains information on how to get the ID. If for whatever reason you need that in the opened page, communicate it via `sendMessage` or similar method.

Comment: sendMessage works only for communication between content script and background page . Here , it is a popup window from background page

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Answer (score 1):

There is no such property like window.id in javascript. However, you have such property in a callback function when using chrome API (chrome.windows.create) but it is not associated with javascript itself (javascript does not recognize internal browser's identification system).

Inside extension scope you can use for example [chrome.tabs.getCurrent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent) method to retrieve  information about current tab. In a callback function you'll have an id. Note that the id is optional and may not be set.